# How to calculate yearly stock beta

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have 33 years of weekly data of a particular stock and S&P500 index return.
I want to calculate 33 yearly stock betas based on 52 weekly observations of stock return.

I know that beta can be calculated using covarience and varience. I have found that pandas has a function pd.rolling.cov, but it does not work. 
module 'pandas' has no attribute 'rolling'

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
stock=pd.read_excel(r"C:\01.xlsx", '2') #read second sheet of excel file
stock['stockreturn']=np.log(stock.AdjCloseStock / stock.AdjCloseStock.shift(1)) #stock ln return
stock['SP500return']=np.log(stock.AdjCloseSP500 / [enter image description here][1]stock.AdjCloseSP500.shift(1)) #SP500 ln return
stock = stock.iloc[1:] #delete first row in dataframe
stock['beta'] = pd.rolling.cov(stock['stockreturn'], stock['SP500return'], 
window=52) / pd.rolling.var(stock['SP500return'], window=52)
```

Frankly speaking I do not know how to get 33 yearly betas out of 33 52-weeks observation. Any help is appreciated.

[print screen of my data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPhB4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were looking for pd.core.window.Rolling.cov.
To spell the method name correctly,
we ask that you [Read The Fine Manual](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.cov.html),

cf [Create rolling covariance matrix in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45062622/create-rolling-covariance-matrix-in-pandas#answer-45063052)

Comment: I have read about rolling cov method, and now it seems to me that it will return not 33 betas but '# observations - 33' betas

Comment: It is possible that you would prefer to compute 33 annual covariance and variances, rather than calling Rolling.cov().